# What would be the actual version number for 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

A client wants me to compile their website to an earlier version of .net.

What the actual syntax would be for 3.5 for my web.config for version in type?  Surely not 3.5.0.0 ?
or can I just remove the version?

code:

```
...
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="index.aspx" defaultUrl="login.aspx" timeout="1440" />
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="AspnetdbConnString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="AspnetdbConnString" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="AspnetdbConnString" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <location path="Management">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="Managers"/>
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
...
```

Regards
Tea

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsHGL-S63RQ

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it's easiest to do this through visual studio

1. Open the project you want to change.
2. In the Solution Explorer toolbar, choose the Properties button.
3. You can also select the project node in Solution Explorer, open the context menu (by right-clicking the node), and select Properties.
4. You should see the settings on the Application tab. If you do not, select it.
5. In the Target Framework dropdown list, choose the .NET Framework version that you want. Then click the OK button.

Also keep in mind that you'd want to change the references to any 4.0 dll's you've currently got in the project.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202.aspx

Comment: But does that change all references in web.config?

Comment: Yep, should take care of it for you :-) just pull the config up after and scan for anything referencing version 4.0. You might have to clean up a couple things by hand.